# Using custom nodejs function in a AWS Lambda layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-lambda-layers

So, I have tried AWS lambda layers and I have no issues with them so far. When I want to put libraries over there that my lambda functions will require after all I needed it put the package jwt-decode in a folder structure like this:

`nodejs/node_modules/jwt-decode` uploaded as .zip no problems.

**The problem** is... I want to also share **my own custom code** between my Lambda functions without publishing it as a npm package. Is that even possible?

Say you have a function that uses jwt-decode and decodes your access token from the authorization header `event.headers.authorization` then it fetches the "sub" identifier from the decoded token. I want to **share this code** because I don't want to write this implementation for each Lambda function that requires the sub identifier.

Comment: I wonder the same thing, have you found an answer?